# How can I Doxygen Fortran main program?

Tags: fortran, doxygen

I have a very short program:

```
!> This is a test.
program main

    implicit none

    integer :: i
    real :: a

    !> THIS IS A LOOP!
    do i = 1,10
        a = 2.0*i
        write(*,*) a
    end do

end program main
```

But in the generated Doxygen docs, only `This is a test.` is shown.
How can I get `THIS IS A LOOP!` to show?
I know it works for subroutines and modules.

Comment: Welcome, I suggest taking the [tour]. Be aware that unlike C, where everything is a function, Fortran distinguishes several types of compilation units: programs, subroutines, functions, modules and also less used block data.

Answer (score 1):

Well, just found a workaround [here](https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/2894).

I'd have to do something like this:

```
program test

call main()

contains

!> This is a test.
subroutine main()

    implicit none

    integer :: i
    real :: a

    !> - THIS IS A LOOP!
    do i = 1,10
        a = 2.0*i
        write(*,*) a
    end do

end subroutine main

end program test
```